# PHP : How to format seconds to this date string format?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a php variable, `$seconds = a number of seconds.`

I want to convert this value to a string format : `'xxh xxmin xxs'` where xx is the value and does not appear if null.

I am currently using the followiing code which works well :

```
$hours = floor($seconds/3600);
$seconds -= $hours * 3600;
$minutes = floor($seconds/60);
$seconds -= $minutes *60;

$string='';
if ($hours) $string .= $hours . 'h';
$string = $string ? $string . ' ' : $string;
if ($minutes) $string.= $minutes .'min';
$string = $string ? $string . ' ' : $string;
if ($seconds) $string .= $seconds . 's';

return trim($string);
```

Would there not be a direct way of doing this with gmdate ? The following keeps values when null, not what I'm looking for.

```
gmdate('H\h i\m\i\n s\s', $duration) : '';
```

Comment: If you're doing a lot of time manipulation, you might get good usage out of [carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)

Comment: No, there is no direct way with `gmdate()`, so you are "stuck" with `if` statements. And your code works for you, why change it?

Comment: ahha, that's just out of curiosity. I might have learnt a better way to do it

Comment: So were are we with this question?

Comment: stuck with my original solution for now. I don't think gmdate can conditionally display values

Comment: @Sébastien Did you even see my answer?

Comment: You say you're stuck with your original solution, but never said something to my answer if it worked or not.

Comment: sorry Rizier, as Glavic pointed it 2 times, the initial solution was not what I was looking for. Your edit is now an acceptable answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, set it to `00:00:00` and then you can just add your seconds with [`modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php), like this:

```
<?php

    $seconds = 350;

    $date = new DateTime("00:00:00");
    $date->modify("+ $seconds seconds");
    echo $date->format("H:i:s");

?>
```

output:

```
00:05:50
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to show the value if it is 0, then just use this:

```
echo implode(" ", array_filter(explode(":", $date->format("H\h:i\m\i\\n:s\s")), function($v){return $v != 0;}));
```

output:

```
05min 50s
```

Comment: OP said `I want to convert this value to a string format : 'xxh xxmin xxs' where xx is the value and does not appear if null.`, so this is basically wrong answer.

Comment: @Glavić Then he just can use it this way: `echo $date->format("H\h:i\m\i\n:s\s");`

Comment: No, this will not work for his needs, since he said, if value is zero, it should not show.

Comment: @Glavić Where does he say that, that he doesn't want to show it, when the value is zero?

Comment: could be condensed in one line with gmdate