# Converting Seconds to display time in HH:MM:SS

Tags: php

I know this should be easy but I am pulling seconds from a db table and need to display this in h:m:s.

My code is this

```
<p style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 1px;">'.($result->time/1000 < 1 ? 0 : $result->time/1000).' <b>Time</b></p>
```

Time in the db is store in seconds x 1000.

Any ideas to have this display in the format would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Mike

Comment: what is wrong with the normal `date` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP : How to format seconds to this date string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955781/php-how-to-format-seconds-to-this-date-string-format). The format can be H:i:s, https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: `seconds x 1000` sounds like milliseconds

Comment: Thank you all, this really helped. All sorted.

Answer (score -1):

Get the total value of seconds  from your db and use the below javascript function to convert it to HH:MM:SS

```
function convertHMS(value) {
const sec = parseInt(value, 10); // convert value to number if it's string
let hours   = Math.floor(sec / 3600); // get hours
let minutes = Math.floor((sec - (hours * 3600)) / 60); // get minutes
let seconds = sec - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60); //  get seconds
// add 0 if value < 10; Example: 2 => 02
if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds; // Return is HH : MM : SS
}
```

If you want to do that from mysql end you can use the function SEC_TO_TIME
Here is an example below

```
 SELECT SEC_TO_TIME('your value seconds here') AS Time;
```

in PHP :

```
 $seconds = round($seconds);

 $output = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($seconds/ 3600),($seconds/ 60 % 
 60), $seconds% 60);
```

Comment: the question is php related, you are showing here javascript

Comment: I thought he need to do it from sql database , and you still can use javascript in php 
Creating function to call it no problem

Comment: How to use Javascript in PHP? That sounds like a pretty difficult thing if you simply want to convert seconds to the given format

Comment: Probably with current implementation it is safe to assume JS is available. PHP doesn't require JS or browser though. PHP can do this natively (DB likely can too).

Comment: here is a php code as well